# I can't map through the array 'products'(React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a get request with a thunk function and save the response inside an array so I could map through it

so here's how we are fetching the api:

```
function fetchProducts() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsPending());
        fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches')
        .then(res => res.json()
        
        )
        .then(
          res => {
            if(res.error) {
                throw(res.error);
            }
            dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(res.products));
            return res.products;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchProductsError(error));
        })
    }
}

export default fetchProducts;
```

I initialized products as empty array and created the store:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const initialState = {
  pending: false,
  products: [],
  error: null
}
const middlewares = [thunk];

export const store=createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

here's the action:

```
const FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING';
 const FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS';
 const FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR';

function fetchProductsPending() {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING
    }
}

function fetchProductsSuccess(products) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        products: products
    }
}

function fetchProductsError(error) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR,
        error: error
    }
}
```

and here's the reducer:

```
export function productsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: true
            }
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                products: action.payload
            }
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                error: action.error
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

so now I need to map the dispatch to props, so I imported fetchProducts in the class component ProductView:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import fetchProducts from './App';
import {getProductsError, getProducts, getProductsPending} from './App';
import Product from './Product'



class ProductView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.shouldComponentRender = this.shouldComponentRender.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {fetchProducts} = this.props;
        fetchProducts();
    }

    shouldComponentRender() {
        const {pending} = this.props;
        if(this.pending === false) return false;
        // more tests
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        const {products, error, pending} = this.props;

       

        return (
            <div className='product-list-wrapper'>
                {error && <span className='product-list-error'>{error}</span>}
                <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>{products.map((product)=>(<Grid item key={product.mission_name} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}><Product product={product} /></Grid>))}</Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    error: getProductsError(state),
    products: getProducts(state),
    pending: getProductsPending(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    fetchProducts: fetchProducts
}, dispatch)

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ProductView );
```

now I am getting error that 'products' can't be mapped over
here's the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
ProductView.render
C:/Users/SUPPORT/Downloads/redux dashboard/my-app/src/ProductView.js:39
  36 |     return (
  37 |         <div className='product-list-wrapper'>
  38 |             {error && <span className='product-list-error'>{error}</span>}
> 39 |             <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>{products.map((product)=>(<Grid item key={product.mission_name} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}><Product product={product} /></Grid>))}</Grid>
     | ^  40 |         </div>
  41 |     )
  42 | }
```

and here's the codeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sunset-wxefc?file=/src/style.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your action, you return type & products

```
function fetchProductsSuccess(products) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        products: products
    }
}
```

But in your reducer when you read it, you are reading from action.payload

```
    return {
        ...state,
        pending: false,
        products: action.payload
    }
```

It should be action.products or change the action te return payload: products

```
    return {
        ...state,
        pending: false,
        products: action.products
    }
```

Comment: I tried to replace action.payload to action.products and gave same error:https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sunset-wxefc?file=/src/App.js